# Upload to S3 via Cloudfront

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So as we all know [Cloudfront now supports uploading to S3](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/) via the edge points.

However, I'm not really sure how to do this? I know it'll not be fully featured (i.e. not support authorize headers and part uploads) but I'm keen to do straight uploads.

I'm working in PHP, though it doesn't appear this is supported on the API yet as a method. Doing something rather simpler looks to require various authorisation milestones.

Has anyone found the best way to do this yet or just some suggestions for the best way as I'm trying CURL POST and other such things to no avail.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to upload to S3 via Cloudfront?  I've seen occasional questions about this, but fail to see any reason why anyone would actually want to do it.  Enlighten me?

Comment: Simply, that it's quicker to upload to your local edge point than uploading to the S3 end-point for users not regionally close to your S3 end-point. Remember S3 is regional.

Comment: Yes, but when you upload through cloudfront, you aren't uploading "to" your local edge location... you are still uploading all the way "to" the S3 origin and the upload is merely proxying "through" cloudfront to get there.  The upload isn't being saved to the edge location.

Comment: Yes, but peering from an AWS edge centre to your AWS S3 location is likely to be a bit speedier. No? I mean - this is AWS advice. If you know different I'd like to hear so we can save time investment. I'm interested to know why AWS have even bothered providing this functionality if there's nothing to be gained. Right now we have a lot of delays/issues with distant uploads.

Comment: It seems like most questions around this are being answered with SO typical "no point in that". Be great to have some feedback from those who have tried, proven any improvements/done some testing etc... anyone out there?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably read more about the [browser-based POST uploads feature of Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html) on the AWS docs. Doing an  POST upload to Amazon S3 requires you to send a special JSON policy doc along with your POST request and upload. The [S3 `PostObject` class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.Model.PostObject.html) in the AWS SDK for PHP is helpful for generating this policy, based on your provided options, as well as generating other form element values you need to include with your form/request.

Though I haven't tried it yet, you probably just need to swap out the S3 bucket endpoint for your CloudFront distribution endpoint to do the upload via the CloudFront edge location. Also, make sure your distribution is configured to accept POST requests. To get a more official answer to your question, I'd ask the Amazon CloudFront team on the [CloudFront forum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.aws.amazon.com%2Fforum.jspa%3FforumID%3D46&ei=QNiYUpOfGdXaoASNhYCIDA&usg=AFQjCNHoZWdmpKJhzH8VJGoGjd-ZclxXFw&sig2=mSQeRSrbunyYP70ycIAMRw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.cGU).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this now, I would give it another try.  Be sure to use the S3 bucket's DNS name when signing your request, not your CloudFront distribution's.